# RTK Query: How store data into specific state path while ignoring dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Right now, I'm using Redux Toolkit Query to fetch data from API.
But that API required a new signature in the query parameter every time we send a request. As in the code below:

```js
export const restApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "restApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query({
      query: ({ name, signature }) => `${name}?signature=${signature}`
    }),
  }),
});
```

Which redux will save it in a different state path as below image
[image]

My question is, how do I make rtk-query ignore the signature parameter and just update the state of the request with the same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is available on the query endpoints a [`serializeQueryArgs`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs-1) property that allows for providing "a custom cache key value based on the query arguments". This seems to be exactly what you are asking for.

Example:

```js
export const restApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "restApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query({
      query: ({ name, signature }) => `${name}?signature=${signature}`,
      serializeQueryArgs: ({ queryArgs }) => {
        const { name } = queryArgs;
        return { name }; // omit `signature` from the cache key
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```